# Method Overriding and Optional Parameters

Tags: c#, inheritance, optional-parameters, overriding

Would someone care to explain how this code produces the folowing output?

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Test
    {
        public override string ToString() { return "ToString override"; }
        public string ToString(string optional = "")
          { return String.Format("ToString with optional parameter {0}", optional); }
    }

    class Test2
    {
        public new string ToString() { return "ToString new"; }
        public string ToString(string optional = "")
          { return String.Format("ToString with optional parameter {0}", optional); }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test one = new Test();
            Test2 two = new Test2();
            Console.WriteLine(one);
            Console.WriteLine(one.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(one.ToString("foo"));
            Console.WriteLine("--");
            Console.WriteLine(two);
            Console.WriteLine(two.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(two.ToString("bar"));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

> ToString override
>
> ToString with optional parameter
>
> ToString with optional parameter foo
>
> --
>
> ConsoleApplication1.Test2
>
> ToString new
>
> ToString with optional parameter bar

Comment: Which line do you not understand? (It would be tedious to go into detail about all of them.)

Comment: Basically how the compiler chooses between the different methods, since they have identical signatures.

Comment: They don't have identical signatures... and again, it would help if you'd say *which* lines you're stuck on. How much have you tried to understand how overload resolution works? By the way, there's no such thing as C# 4.5.

Comment: It is written in specification.

Comment: If the signatures were truly identical, the compiler wouldn't allow them. The compiler allows them, therefore they aren't truly identical.

Comment: The part about `Console.WriteLine(one)` and `Console.WriteLine(two)` is fairly straightforward. `Console.WriteLine()` takes an object. Your `Test` class overrides `ToString()`, so you get a fairly obvious result. `Test2` does NOT override `ToString()`, and since `WriteLine` is looking for an `object`, it does not find the `new string ToString()` function.

Comment: As for why it seems to prefer the "new" ToString to the optional parameter, and the optional parameter to the override... I'm very curious about that.

Comment: Ah, I think I might have worked it out actually... Its because it would rather use a method defined on the object than one defined on a parent so it uses the optional parameter method (since it was defined on the object) rather than the paramterless one defined on a base class (or something like that)... This is ringing vague bells from probably Jon Skeet explaining it to me before...

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Okay, as there's general interest, here's a quick version:

**Console.WriteLine(one)**

This will use the `WriteLine(object)` overload, which will in turn execute the `object.ToString()` virtual method, overridden in `One` - hence the output of `ToString override`

**Console.WriteLine(one.ToString())**

This will look at `One` and see which methods have *newly declared methods* - discounting overrides. There's exactly one such method which is applicable - the one with the optional parameter. So that gets executed, using the default value, leading to output of `ToString with optional parameter`.

**Console.WriteLine(one.ToString("foo"))**

Same again, but this time the compiler doesn't need to use the default value, hence `ToString with optional parameter foo`

**Console.WriteLine(two)**

Again, this will call the virtual `object.ToString()` method from `WriteLine(object)`. The method hasn't been overridden, so the default implementation returning the name of the type is used, leading to output of `ConsoleApplication1.Test2`.

**Console.WriteLine(two.ToString())**

The compiler looks at all the method declared in `Two` which *aren't* overriding virtual methods. In this case, there are two such methods - the parameterless one and the one with the optional parameter. The parameterless one is included because it's *new* rather than overriding a base class method.

The parameterless method is deemed a "better" candidate because the compiler prefers to call a method which doesn't need any optional parameters filling in. Hence the output is `ToString new`

**Console.WriteLine(two.ToString("bar"))**

Again, the compiler looks at all the method declared in `Two` which *aren't* overriding virtual methods. In this case, there are two such methods - but the parameterless one isn't applicable, leaving just the one with the optional parameter. The compiler doesn't need to *use* the default value of the optional parameter here, as it's got an argument anyway... so the output is `ToString with optional parameter bar`

For much more on this, read the C# language specification - or for a half-way house, see my [article on overloading](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx).

Comment: Good stuff Jon (as usual). I was slowly getting round to working it all out. The main potential surprise points being that it uses `object.ToString()` and not the `ToString` on the object and the fact it prefers newly defined methods to inherited ones.

Comment: Good Guy Jon Skeet: says "It would be tedious to go into detail about all of them", goes into detail about all of them.

Comment: Yes, that is quite illuminating! Sorry for the trouble. I was getting hung up on the same things as Chris, above - the object.ToString explains the difference between the override in one and new in two, and the fact that the compiler prefers newly declared methods explains the one.ToString().

Comment: And then says - this is a quick version. <shakes head>

Comment: @ananthonline: I didn't take the time to include spec references :)

Comment: Spec link - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691336(v=vs.71).aspx